# make column data as hyperlink (dataTable JQUERY)

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am trying to make a column as hyperlink with datatable but no success.

function successCallback(responseObj){

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#example').dataTable( {
        "data":responseObj ,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "deferRender": true ,
        "columns": [
                    { "data": "infomation" },
                    { "data": "weblink" },
                ]
  } );

  } );
```

}

I need the weblink to display the link and be an hyperlink in that column so users can click and be redirected to another page. I looked into [render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) but with less information there on links, i can't succeed to do it.

I also looked into this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502387/datatables-hyperlink-on-all-rows-in-a-column) but it wasn't very helpful.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use [`columns.render`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) API method to dynamically produce content for a cell.

```js
$('#example').dataTable({
   "data": responseObj,
   "columns": [
      { "data": "information" }, 
      { 
         "data": "weblink",
         "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
            if(type === 'display'){
                data = '<a href="' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
            }

            return data;
         }
      } 
   ]
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/cqamc695/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: What if I also want to make First Column(A1-A4) clickable that would use same link? I have a problem when I want multiple columns clickable, but use same source for `href`. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @Trm, you can define the same `columns.render` function for the rest of the columns, instead of `data` use `row['weblink']`. Or you could use `columnDefs.render` and define `render` function once and target all required columns using `columnDefs.targets` option.

Comment: I tried using `columnsDefs`, maybe I'm missing something, but problem was that different Data was rendered for each column. [Here's how my code looks](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/39633/how-to-set-same-hyperlink-for-multiple-columns#latest)

Comment: @Trm, as I said earlier, use `full['name']` instead of `data`.

Comment: What if I don't have data from an object? What if I just loop with PHP and want anchor tags around the looped data?

Comment: doesn't work in angular 2 and up. The (click) binding will be lost if using columns.render

Comment: @SilentSojourner, use event delegation when attaching click event handlers, please see [this article](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-why-click-event-handler-does-not-work/).

Answer (score 20):

If you are looking to add link based on other column data then can use the below approach.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
   "data": responseObj,
   "columns": [
      { "data": "information" }, 
      { 
         "data": "weblink",
         "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
            if(type === 'display'){
                data = '<a href="' + row.myid + '">' + data + '</a>';
            }
            return data;
         }
      } 
   ]
});
```

I have just changed the *render function*. `data` refers to only current column data, while `row` object refers to entire row of data. Hence we can use this to get any other data for that row.

Comment: How do you work the row selector `row.myid`? The data I provide Ajax has string columns for the cell content and int columns which aren't used to render the cell, but ideally I could use to assemble the link. This is exactly what I am trying to do!

Comment: I am using `rowId: "taskno"` (rowId Option) to set `id` property in HTML for `tr` tag then use `row.myid` to refer/get this. Ref: https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowId

Comment: I ended up assembling the url like so `data = '<a href="/url/' + row['col2'] + '">' + data + '</a>';`

Comment: this answer save my day even its old

Answer (score 9):

```
    $('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 0,
    "data": "download_link",
    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
      return '<a href="'+data+'">Download</a>';
    }
  } ]
} );
```

From the [documentation](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#). It is quite clear and straightforward to me, what is it specifically that you do do not understand? What errors do you see?

For a more complete example, see [here](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html)

Comment: Do you know if there is a workaround if I have `"targets": [0,1]`, they both would use data from first column (target 0)?

Comment: see the documentation link in my answer. the third param is the row data (not sure why in my example I have called the variable "full" but it is an array with all data from the row

Comment: God bless you man. Documentation code samples also says "full", so that's why I guess you called it. I used `full.column_name` to get the data. I've read documentation multi times, but wording never clicked me that it returns full row data.

Answer (score 2):

in my example I make the column cell fully clickable and not just the text inside the column. I think it will be useful for someone. use bootsrap 5

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datatable').DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: '{!! route('get.profiles') !!}',
      columns: [
          {
              data: 'id',
              name: 'id',
              render : function(data, type, row, meta) {return'<a class=" d-inline-block fw-normal w-100 h-100 pe-auto" href="profiles/edit/' + row.id + '">' + row.id + '</a>';},
          },

          {
              data: 'name',
              name: 'name',
              render : function(data, type, row, meta) {return'<a class="d-inline-block fw-normal w-100 h-100 pe-auto" href="profiles/edit/' + row.id + '">' + row.name + '</a>';},
          },
      ]
  });
});
```

in your css file add

```
td{
height: 100%;
overflow: visible;
}
```