# Error rendering html elements using JQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, datatables

I am using Jquery datatable (Server-side) to show the contents of my table. I want to edit of the columns to render some html elements (span and a). However, instead of rendering to a link for example, it returns the raw code. 
This is my view

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>League</th>
  <th>Match</th>
</tr>
</table>
 $('.server_table').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "{{ route('getdata') }}",
            "columns":[
                { "data": "league" },
                { "data": "match" },

            ]
        });
```

My Controller

```
$query = DB::select(); //Runs query
return Datatables::of($query) 
->editColumn('match', function($query){
 $ratings = "default";
 return '<span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#'.$query->user_id.'"><a  onmouseover="bigImg(this)" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click to view user\'s last 5 ratings!">'.$query->username. '['.ucfirst($ratings).']'.'</a>
</span>';
})->make(true)
```

Comment: is it just a typo at the end of `'</a>`? missing `'`

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/30489307/4770813